# Errors relating to \xrfill

Tags: errors

I'm new to using LaTeX and am unsure of how to resolve errors that arise when trying to insert a line broken by text (as a header) into a bibliography. However, it does also happen at any other point in the document. For example, an excerpt of my code for the bibliography is shown below.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\hskip
\xrfill[0.7ex]{1pt}

\item{ITEM 1}

\hrule
\vspace{0.5cm}

\end{thebibliography}
```

The idea is to create a line at the top containing a section number, so that the references within that and the bottom line (the \hrule command) can be clearly attributed to the appropriate sections in a larger report. However, using:

```
\hskip
\xrfill[0.7ex]{1pt}
```

causes some errors to appear, not just in the bibliography. Specifically, on the line where the \xrfill function is called, a "Missing number, treated as zero" error appears. At item 1, an error saying "Something's wrong - perhaps a missing item" also appears. I have used the \xhfill package in my document preamble:

```
\usepackage{xhfill}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Edit: A sketch of what I wanted it to look like:

[image: Sketch of Bibliography]

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks. I've updated the post to include a rough sketch of what I wanted it to look like. I can add more detail if you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{myline}

\newcommand{\myline}{%
    \addtocounter{myline}{1}
    \item[] \hskip-1.8em \hrulefill \raisebox{-0.8ex}{~Section \themyline} \hrulefill\vspace*{0.8ex}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\myline

\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower \emph{Readings compiled for History 21.479.} 1991.

\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973: Random House, N.Y.

\myline

\bibitem{notesa} John W. Dower \emph{Readings compiled for History 21.479.} 1991.

\bibitem{impja}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973: Random House, N.Y.

\myline

\bibitem{notesb} John W. Dower \emph{Readings compiled for History 21.479.} 1991.

\bibitem{impjb}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973: Random House, N.Y.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked rather well. Assuming I have a reference in each section (1-7) then this will be perfect for the document I'm producing. Thanks again.

Comment: @SaifSaleem You're welcome!

Comment: @SaifSaleem In case you won't have a reference in each section, you can skip sections by using `\addtocounter{myline}{1}`

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thanks again for answering the post. You're a legend.